# junit test skips after 600 seconds

Tags: java, web-services, junit, embedded

I'm working on the system test of a IOT device that has various webservices.

We have 2 types, one with slow flash and the newer with faster flash memory. in the new flash the fw update can be done with aprox. 4 minutes while the slow ones take something around 12 minutes.

The problem comes in the junit test that tests the update and go back to the "previous" version. After sending the file and the update signal to the device, i use a Thread.sleep(6*60*1000) to wait for the device to expand the file, update and restart.

The junit test "skips" the test after 600s have passed, not failure, not error, just skips to the next test class..

[It looks like it finished, but it just skipped the rest of the test WHILE it is inside the sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFQon.png)

a small snippet of the test code althought it is mostly propietary:

```
 public RequestCase(String path, WebServiceRequest req, WebServiceResponse resExp, String tcDesc, boolean validateResXSD) {
        //super();
        this.setPath(path);
        this.setReq(req);
        this.setResExp(resExp);
        this.res = new WebServiceResponse();
        this.setTcDesc(tcDesc);
        this.setValidateResXSD(validateResXSD);
}
```

and the test snippet:

```
    // now apply Software
    String s06Req = null;
    try {
        s06Req = WebServiceRequestS06.makeCommandPsu(updFile.getRevision(), WebServiceRequestS06.SW_UPD);
    } catch (WebServiceXMLException e) {
        fail("Error creating S06 XML request. Error is: "+e.getMessage()+"\nAnd cause is :"+e.getCause());
    }

    RequestCase s06CommandPsu = new RequestCase(
            null,
            new WebServiceRequest("commandPsu", "POST", s06Req), 
            WebServiceResponse.RESULT_STATUS_CMD_SW_RECEIVED, 
            "Apply valid SW, and it is only received, but not apply now (imply Y03)", 
            true
    );
    executeCase(s06CommandPsu, WebServicesXSDValidator.S06_CommandPsu);

    // Wait some time to wait charger apply new SW and reboot
    try {
        if (this.charger.getProductType() == Charger.ID_CT1_OLD_FLASH) {
            Thread.sleep(6*60*1000);
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(2*60*1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

can someone help me a bit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. We can't help with code not working when you just describe that code...

Comment: Thanks for your time @GhostCat , i didnt include it because it's quite propietary but i will try to include more so it is more understanable

Comment: That is where "minimal" comes in. You don't have to provide your product code. Just an example that shows the problem!

Comment: i included a picture of the state the eclipse reaches after 600 seconds, the test package counts as finished and it goes to the next package. Sorry about the poor format of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found what was causing this, i will post it just in case someone stomps at the same problem.

it was caused due to the Parallelized class, more specifically in the ExecutorService awaitTermination() method where you can set a timeout..

Answer (score 0):

The test code snippet provided hre is not showing any assert/verify operation.

You have a test that sits there, waiting 600 seconds. Then it will end.
And the test will show up as passed (as it didn't cause a failure or error).

Thus:

1. If your tests should do something after 600 seconds, you have to code that.
2. Unrelated: you really should step back first. Unit tests should pass quickly, having it wait 600 seconds is not a good idea (assuming that we are talking real unit tests here, not an integration test)

Comment: Thank you again for your time, after the delay there are actions to do but even if i put a breakpoint after the delay, it never reaches because the test skips, i even tried to fragment the delay to be of 60seconds and print something but it doesnt complete the whole delay

Comment: @armengedon Given your input, that is all I can contribute here. Again: that is why I asked you for a [mcve]. You want to give us a **full** example of *something* that shows your problem.